# How to modify envi path on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to modify path of android sdk to new path on ubuntu.

with command "printenv PATH", terminal is printing ...

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/gangadhar/Work/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/platform-tools:/home/gangadhar/Work/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/tools:/home/gangadhar/Work/Android/android-ndk-r9d
```

but I would like to change it from /home/gangadhar/Work/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/tools new path

Some one, Please help me. Thank you

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3744/how-do-i-modify-my-path-so-that-the-changes-are-available-in-every-terminal-sess

are you looking for this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your .bashrc file (which is in your home directory) add this line

```
EXPORT PATH=$PATH:/path/to/new/directory
```

Then reload your bashrc with

```
source ~/.bashrc
```